# Inject RxHttpClient in Micronaut with url coming from an environment variable

Tags: groovy, micronaut

When I am injecting a RxHttpClient in micronaut, I have an url with a token that I want to get from an environment variable to avoid hardcoding a secret.

In my service, I have injected the client like this:

```
@Client('${System.getenv(\'BOT_URL\')}')
@Inject
RxHttpClient httpClient
```

Being BOT_URL my url that's stored in an environment variable.
The project build but it fails while trying to use the client with this error:

```
2021-03-20 20:05:14.37 Could not resolve placeholder ${System.getenv('BOT_KEY')}
```

My variable is correctly defined in the server, how can I access to it when injecting the client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Micronaut* ships with pre-made `PropertySourceLoader`s that will resolve `PropertySource`s from different sources. You can read more on [externalized configuration](https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/index.html#propertySource) through the docs.

Besides these `PropertySourceLoader`s, `PropertySource`s are resolved from environment variables and are automatically injected and available for use within the `ApplicationContext` following the property source key syntax:

i.e. ***SOME_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE*** translates to ***some.environment.variable***

Hence you can simply inject your `HttpClient` declaratively with the environment variable key translated to dot-separated-property-key syntax:

```
@Client('${bot.url}')
@Inject
RxHttpClient httpClient
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to access environment variables just using `${BOT_URL}`. I know for a fact that this works in the `application.yml` file. If it doesn't work in the annotation you can always create a property in `application.yml` with the value of the environment variable and use the property in your annotation.

For the docs on this, try the "Property value binding" section of the [micronaut docs](https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/index.html).